# how to change data type using MSSQL query

Tags: sql-server

```
--ADB sample data
student_id  gender__id  year_of_birth   month_of_birth  day_of_birth
333423              2           2001            2             4
333503              2           2001            11            5
333243              2           NULL            NULL          NULL
333536              1           2001            7             25
333199              1           2001            1             1
333455              1           2001            11            23
338866              1           2001            12            30
339365              1           NULL            NULL          NULL
```

.
.
.

```
--BDB sample data
ID         sex      birthday
AB332748    2   1999-08-01
AB332804    1   1989-01-15
AB333152    1   24591
AB333455    1   2001-11-23
```

.
.
.

```
 --Expected result
 student_id  gender__id    year_of_birth    month_of_birth    day_of_birth  time_of_birth          ID        sex          birthday
   332748         2            2001            2                    4         NULL                332748       2         1999-08-01
   332804         2            2001           11                    5         NULL                 332804      1         1989-01-15
   333152         2            NULL           NULL                  NULL      NULL                333152       1         24591
   333455         1           2001            7                    25         NULL                333455       1         2001-11-23
   333593         1           2001            1                     1         NULL                333593       2         1943-05-26
   333693         1           2001           11                    23         NULL                333693       2         1939-02-25
   334304         1           2001           12                    30         NULL                334304       2         1956-03-07
   334326        1            NULL           NULL                  NULL       NULL                334326       2         1963-04-04
```

I made some sql query code using two tables of different datatypes. MSSQL version is MSSQL server 2017 developer edition.

```
--problem sqlquery source code
SELECT ID,
       sex,
       birthday,
       student_id,
       gender_id,
       year_of_birth,
       month_of_birth,
       day_of_birth,
       time_of_birth
FROM ADB.dbo.PERSON
     LEFT JOIN BDB.dbo.BASE_demo ON CAST(ADB.dbo.PERSON.student_id AS INT) = CAST(REPLACE(BDB.dbo.B_demo.ID, 'AB', '') AS int)
                                AND ADB.dbo.PERSON.student_id = BDB.dbo.BASE_demo.ID
WHERE BDB.dbo.BASE_demo.ID LIKE 'AB%'
  AND ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(BDB.dbo.BASE_demo.ID, 'AB', '')) = 1;
```

After debugging top code, There is some problem like this message.

There didn't change from `nvarchar` value `'AB332748'` to data type `int`.

Do you know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: You already asked this question (though its deleted now).

Comment: How do you expect 'AB' to be converted to `INT`? Maybe you need to extract the numeric part and then try for convert.

Comment: I made my comments on your other duplicate (and deleted) topic. They've not changed.

Comment: @HoneyBadger yeah. I know. But I post on this site again  because my question was lack

Comment: @Larnu Sorry, I couldn't your comments.

Comment: "Couldn't my comments"? You're missing a verb there.

Comment: @Abhishek I already used convert function. It didn't work. And.... I want to see result data (' AB332748' -> '332748')

Comment: @Larnu I just confirmed your message, you said "What version of SQL Server? Really, you should be using TRY_CONVERT instead of ISNUMERIC..Where is the value B.dbo.BASE_demo.ID coming from? You don't have any objects called, or aliased, B. Also you have the clause ON CAST(ADB.dbo.PERSON.student_id AS INT) = CAST(REPLACE(BDB.dbo.B_demo.ID, 'AB', '') AS int) AND ADB.dbo.PERSON.student_id = BDB.dbo.B_demo.ID. Very likely, one of those is not going to evaluate to true. Can you post some sample data and expected results please?"

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this, however, this is my guess. There's no expected output here (which the OP has acknowledged I asked for), nor have they advised that what version of SQL Server they have, so i'm trusting they have SQl Server 2012+ (if they are using 2008 or prior then an upgrade should be pretty high on the list of "thing to do").

If this doesn't work, or provide the expected results, see the abvoe paragraph:

```
SELECT ID, --Missing Table Alias
       sex, --Missing Table Alias
       birthday, --Missing Table Alias
       student_id, --Missing Table Alias
       gender_id, --Missing Table Alias
       year_of_birth, --Missing Table Alias
       month_of_birth, --Missing Table Alias
       day_of_birth, --Missing Table Alias
       time_of_birth --Missing Table Alias
FROM ADB.dbo.PERSON P
     JOIN BDB.dbo.BASE_demo B ON P.student_id TRY_CONVERT(int,STUFF(B.ID,1,2,'')) --This is non-SARGable
WHERE B.ID LIKE 'AB%'
  AND TRY_CONVERT(int,STUFF(B.ID,1,2,'')) IS NOT NULL;
```

Note that I have used an `INNER JOIN`. Using a `LEFT JOIN` and then referencing the table in your `WHERE` without coping for `NULL`s turn the join into an implicit `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @platanus yes, I know. I stated that in my answer.

Comment: To quote myself: *"If this doesn't work, or provide the expected results, see the abvoe paragraph"*

Comment: @platanus Then post the expected results, like I've asked for 4 times please.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the sample data - only one record (ID: 333455) exists in both `ADB.dbo.PERSON` and `BDB.dbo.BASE_demo`, assuming that `ADB.dbo.PERSON.student_id` maps to `BDB.dbo.BASE_demo.ID`, just with 'AB' prepended to it (as appears to be the case based on the OP's query).  So, since there is no record with ID 333152 in `ADB.dbo.PERSON`, there's no way to duplicate that row in the Expected result provided.

That said, I'd use a CTE to manipulate `BDB.ID` accordingly, and then join to that.  Here is my full repro:

```
-- set up tables
Create Table ADB 
(
    Student_ID Int
    , Gender_ID TinyInt
    , Year_of_Birth Int
    , Month_of_Birth Int
    , Day_of_Birth Int
)

Create Table BDB
(
    ID Varchar(20)
    , Sex TinyInt
    , Birthday Varchar(20)
)

Insert Into dbo.ADB
(
    Student_ID
    , Gender_ID
    , Year_of_Birth
    , Month_of_Birth
    , Day_of_Birth
)
Select 333423, 2, 2001, 2, 4
Union All Select 333503, 2, 2001, 11, 5
Union All Select 333243, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL
Union All Select 333536, 1, 2001, 7, 25
Union All Select 333199, 1, 2001, 1, 1
Union All Select 333455, 1, 2001, 11, 23
Union All Select 338866, 1, 2001, 12, 30
Union All Select 339365, 1, NULL, NULL, Null

Insert Into dbo.BDB
(
    ID
    , Sex
    , Birthday
)
Select 'AB332748', 2, '1999-08-01'
Union All Select 'AB332804', 1, '1989-01-15'
Union All Select 'AB333152', 1, '24591'
Union All Select 'AB333455', 1, '2001-11-23'

-- here's the code.  I was on SQL 2012, so no Try_Cast()
;with CTE_bdb as
(
    Select
        Cast(Replace(ID, 'AB', '') as Int) As ID,  
        sex,
        birthday
    From dbo.BDB
    Where ID LIKE 'AB%'
    And IsNumeric(Replace(ID, 'AB', '')) = 1
)

Select 
    a.student_id,
    a.gender_id,
    a.year_of_birth,
    a.month_of_birth,
    a.day_of_birth,
    Null as time_of_birth,
    b.ID,
    b.sex,
    b.birthday
From dbo.ADB As a
    Left Outer Join CTE_bdb as b
        On A.student_id = b.ID
```

Here is my output (apologies for the formatting - I can't figure out how to make it look like how you did in your initial post):

`student_id gender_id   year_of_birth   month_of_birth  day_of_birth    time_of_birth   ID  sex birthday
333423  2   2001    2   4   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
333503  2   2001    11  5   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
333243  2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
333536  1   2001    7   25  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
333199  1   2001    1   1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
333455  1   2001    11  23  NULL    333455  1   2001-11-23
338866  1   2001    12  30  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
339365  1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL`

Comment: Thank you. Brian. But. I tested code that you give, There is tested result as follow. I can't confirm ID, sex, birthday on BDB. BDB values have all null.

Comment: As I said, I don't have an instance available right now to test.  I'll take a look at it in the morning.

Comment: @platanus, I've updated my answer after testing it.  I found one extraneous comma, which I removed.

Comment: Thank you for interest my question. thanks to you, I resolved  my problems.

Comment: Glad to hear it, and you're very welcome.  That's why we're here.